# What does "put someone on his/her back" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the TV show *House of cards*, angry President Garry Walker finds out his vice president, Frank, has been betraying him possibly to replace him as president. Garry says to Frank:

> From this moment forward, I don’t want to hear your voice. I don’t want to see your face. And if I do, I will put you on your goddamn back.

I suspect it is a figurative way of saying I will kill you, or maybe hurt you, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It means to throw someone to the ground, on their back, to their hurt and disadvantage.

Comment: Like a turtle on it's shell. Get it now?

Answer (score 4):

I interpret it as meaning that Garry will hit or throw Frank to the ground (possibly [knock him out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/knock-out-someone)), the result being that Frank would be on his back. That's the physical interpretation. You could also interpret it figuratively, suggesting that Gary would harm Frank's career.

To imply death, I think a different expression would be used, like

> And if I do, I will [put you [six feet under](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/six+feet+under)]/[[bury](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bury) you].

Though, both (especially "bury you") could also suggest ending Frank's career.